# How to avoid duplicate backstack entries

Tags: android, fragment-backstack

I am working on an app that has a lot of fragments and while navigating through them  each fragment is added to the backstack ... What I want to achieve is that I don't want duplicate backstack entries. ...e.g if I have four fragments f1,f2,f3,f4 and if I navigate through f1-f2-f3-f1-f4-f3 fragments f1 and f3 are added two times  ....is there a way I can check if the fragment is already in the backstack so duplicate entries won't b added ?

Comment: are you using TAG also?

Comment: I am new to Android ... Any help would b appreciated

Answer (score 0):

since you creating new refreneces to the fragments there will be always duplicates my Suggestion to you is : 
1.Insert with TAG : it lets you use `findFragmentByTag(String tag)` with `FragmentManager` so it wont be any duplicates
2.use Singleton on the Selected Fragments : Singleton will return exist refrence of the Fragment.. (usual not used but Backstack Entries are kinda tricky)